# Alert Dialog disappears when actionbar/ status bar of device scrolled down

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

Splash screen activity is full screen and I am checking for internet connection using following link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

I have implemented 2 buttons for alertdialog RETRY and CLOSE. On close click I'm terminating app.
On retry click calling function to check internet connection.
When I try to connect to internet by pulling down the actionbar/statusbar of device the alert dialog disappears.

My Internet checking function is called just after setcontentview from oncreate function.

following is my code:

```
Inside on create function
cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
checkInternet();


public void checkInternet()
{
    Log.i("INTERNET CONNECTION CHECKING", "CHECKING INTERNET CONNECTION");
    // get Internet status
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

    if (isInternetPresent) 
    {
        // Internet Connection is Present
        // make HTTP requests
        //showAlertDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Internet Connection", "You have internet connection", true);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Internet connection is not present
        // Ask user to connect to Internet
        showAlertDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                "Please Retry or close.", false);
    }
}

public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) 
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon
    //alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            checkInternet();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            //finish();
             android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: why downvote can anyone please explain me?

Comment: No code, and no stack trace on error.

Comment: provided link from which i have implemented code.

Comment: First, no one is going read another site to understand your issue and help you.
Second, no stack trace, we can't troubleshoot the issue.  I have some ideas, but only 50% sure without detail stacktrace and your actual code.

Comment: I have added code which i implemented now can you please remove my downvotes. I am not getting any error but the alert dialog disappears

Comment: Did it go in to CheckInternet again after you pull the notification?
`Log.i("INTERNET CONNECTION CHECKING", "CHECKING INTERNET CONNECTION");`

Comment: @uDevel its not going in checkinternet function after i pull notification.

Comment: Not sure what is your app trying to do, but if you move `checkInternet();` to onResume, it would check again when you pull notification back up.

Comment: I solved the issue it was due to my app screen being in fullscreen (no title bar full screen). So I removed the fullscreen parameters and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the full screen mode of Splash Screen, so you will be directly accessible to status bar of your device